# Javascript timeout - specification

Tags: javascript, timeout

This is more than a question, it is a request to ensure the Quality of Service (QoS) of Javascript's timeout function.

Looking at the following pseudo-code:

```
  .. start something in JS after a user action
  .. some js code
  setTimeout( function() { doSomething }, 1 );
  .. continue for longer than 1ms doing something
  .. end code for user action

  .. after 

  .. execute doSomething
```

Can we be sure that on all major browsers, the code of the timeout is done after the code has handled the first user action? This is independent of the delay time.

The delay time is not important, rather the fact 'doSomething' code is executed after.

What happens with 0 delay?

Thanks in advance for your experience on different browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an asynchronous event "fires" is different from when it actually executes, due to Javascript's single-threaded nature.

Each block of code being evaluated is represented internally as a task in a task queue. So let's say that in the middle of a given block of code, an asynchronous event is prepped for execution via `setTimeout()`. If the delay is short enough, in practice nothing's stopping it from "firing" before the rest of that same block of code is finished executing. However "firing" doesn't mean that the `setTimeout` handler actually interrupts and executes. It just means that it's turned into a task on a task queue. Actual execution still has to wait until it is popped off of the task queue, and that can't happen until the original block of code is finished.

Here's an HTML5 spec snippet that, while not authoritative for all browsers of course, being HTML5, is illustrative:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#processing-model-3

The first of 7 steps defined there for the main event loop is:

1. **Run the oldest task on one of the event loop's task queues**, ignoring tasks whose associated Documents are not fully active [...]

Note that this first step is atomic.  The task must run to completion before the environment is reset and the next task is picked up.

Also have a look at John Resig's post on this:
http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

So, wrt your question:

> Can we be sure that on all major browsers the code of the timeout is done after the code handling the first user action. This independently of the delay time.

... the answer is yes, we can be sure. (In the vanilla case... I assume we're only talking about the traditional single/UI thread, and not talking about processing by Web Workers).

Also, although you did mention that you don't care as much about the delay time per se, still you may be interested to note the "clamp time" (enforced minimum delay) as well, which appears to be [de facto standardized at around 4ms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting).

Comment: Thanks for the note on "clamp time". There is always something interesting and new to learn on SO.

Comment: Impressive answer, thanks. Just waiting a bit to accept it

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` is implementation dependent and it does not guarantee a callback within the specified  timeout. You should instead consider timeout parameter as a hint to the underlying engine suggesting your preference on when you like the registered function to be called back. The callback may be delayed indefinitely if the browser is busy/stuck in a long running script. This will be clear when you consider browsers are single threaded.

Timeout 0, simply put implies indicates that you would like the engine to invoke the registered function as soon as it is feasible.

By registering a timeout, you are just booking a slot in the browsers event queue. You will be guaranteed a callback, but the duration on wait is determined by lot of other factors and not by the timeout value alone (although that is a significant factor).

Comment: Ashwin, thanks. the question is not about the QoS on the execution time, but the guarantee the code is executed after the 'current' code threat.

Comment: @icCube You can definitely consider it guaranteed. But the caveat is the browser should not be frozen/stuck indefinitely, in which case the call back will obviously not happen.