# setInterval stop working on alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a MCQs quiz and there is a time for each question. I have also used `onbeforeunload` in my script to prevent the user from accidentally navigating away from the quiz page. But when that alert gets display my `setInterval` counter stop working. How can i make the countdown to not stop even if there is an alert?

To further explain my problem here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jvQsq/)

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded so that's not possible. But you can record the date() the alert appears and then the date() alert disappears. You might find some help with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731865/prevent-onbeforeunload-function-from-pausing-javascript-timer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browser dialogs are blocking. All script execution stops when they are open. You cannot change this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What can be the alternate solution to this problem? What if the user came to know that the countdown stop every time he tries to refresh the page but than decide to stay on the page? It gives him extra time for each question

Comment: Alternately, base it on a time calculation (now minus start) instead of a timer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of starting with 90 seconds and trying to reduce that by 1 second every second, calculate the current date + the 90 seconds to get the end date. Then on each call of your `setTimeout`, calculate the current number of seconds until the end date.

The timer won't advance while the alert is visible, but it will skip to where it should be when the alert is dismissed.

Comment: but that will still not kick in while the alert box is open, will it...?

Comment: You won't get an active ticking down while the alert is up, but the timer will skip ahead to where it should be when the alert is dismissed.

Comment: @webeno Correct.  But once the alert is closed it will readjust

Comment: @mmmshuddup True that, I guess it depends on if the OP is fine with the alert to stay once the time is up...

Comment: Actually i have to show the next question after the time is up. As Kivak guided me to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731865/prevent-onbeforeunload-function-from-pausing-javascript-timer) this can be helpful but than i have to calculate how much time has been elapsed since the alert was open and close and than skip all those questions between that time period. E.g each question has 1 min 30 sec and if the total time the alert was open was of 3 min than 2 question needed to be skipped

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround could be that you declare a `var timeCount = new Date()` to store the time if a `beforeunload()` is called and use that to calculate passed time/missed seconds. But otherwise what **Diodeus** said is correct.