# How to get Angular to increment counter while alert popup is visible?

Tags: angularjs

In this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/6pn8tb83/1), Angular increments a number every second, yet when an alert window pops up, the counting stops and when I close the alert window, I get the error

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

This error link actually takes me to a page which seems to be explaining what I need to do, but since I'm not explicitly using `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$digest()`, I don't understand what I need to do so that Angular simply continues to increment and show the incremented number while the alert window is popped up.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>Angular is counting: {{counter}}</div>
    <button ng-click="processFiles()">processFiles</button>
    <div>{{message}}</div>
</div>
```

---

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {

    var theTimer = $interval(function () {
        $scope.counter++;
    }, 1000);           

    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.message = 'click button';

    $scope.processFiles = function() {
        alert('ok');
    }
}
```

Comment: In my browser counter is stopped when i see alert but not getting any error after closing alert.

Comment: I think you should use something more userfriendly than alert, and that it may solve your problem. See Bootstrap's modals for example

Comment: Yes, if I click the alert box closed fast enough, I don't get the error either, but if you wait a few seconds after the alert opens before you close it, you'll see the error, at least I do in Firefox.

Comment: The alert stops all running scripts (check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22973386/5400917), so as @Aaron GOUZIT's suggestion, you should use a custom modal to overcome it

Comment: Something a-sync would do the trick I think.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour. Script execution stops when browser dialogues are open. 
Workaround is to get the time difference between the alert and updating the counter with it, another one is to create your own modal